# Multicast forwarding in switch

Tags: networking

Could you explain, how switch will forward multicast traffic.For normal unicast traffic it will look into the switch table and make decision on which port to send packet.Can you explain what switch will do incase of multicast traffic.

Comment: This question is not about programming, so it is off-topic here. You should ask this type of question on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Some switches treat multicast as broadcast. Others filter based on multicast subscribers joining using IGMP for IPv4, or MLD for IPv6.

A sender just transmits UDP multicast and receivers join (send membership reports) groups to tell switches to forward the sender's data to them.